# How to redirect a user to their own IP Address using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect a user to their own IP Address using htaccess and RewriteRule?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/
```

Comment: This is being blocked by noscript, is there a way it doesnt?